# Post id attribute value to controller ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Suppose we have three hyperlink tag in asp.net mvc. Each of tag has an unique id attribute. How can I post value of id attribute of selected hyperlink to the controller?

Hyperlinks are like this :

```
    <a href="#" id="1" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false; ">A</a>
    <a href="#" id="2" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false; ">B</a>
    <a href="#" id="3" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false; ">C</a>
```

The dialog just opens a form to upload an image and send the image to controller.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        height: 170,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false
    })
});
```

and calling controller method:

```
<div id="dialog" title="A" >
          <% using (Html.BeginForm("myMethod", "Controller", new { @Id = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
               {%>
                <p><input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" style="width:23;"/> </p>
                <p><input type="submit" value="B" /></p>
          <% } %>

       </div>
```

I'm not forced only to send Id. However I have to send a different parameter when different hyperlink is selected to determine which of them is selected.

Answer (score 0):

do something like this

```
<a href="#" id="1" onclick="click(this);">A</a>
<a href="#" id="2" onclick="click(this)">B</a>
<a href="#" id="3" onclick="click(this)">C</a>
<script>
function click(a){
 var $a = $(a);
 //and do anything here
 //access the id like
 var id = $a.attr('id');
}
</script>
```

Comment: I changed code to this : ` <div class="imageToEdit" >
             <img src='<%: Url.Action("getImg", "Product", new{ShopId = Model.Id}) %>'   alt="" />
             <a href="#" id="1" onclick="jQuery('#dialog').dialog('open'); return false; click(a); ">A</a>             
        </div>`   and the script : ` <script>
     function click(a) {
         var $a = $(a);
         var id1 = $a.attr('id');
         imageTypSelected = id1;
     }
</script>` But when I put the `imageTypSelected` in calling controller nothing post to method.  `imageTypSelected` is a global variable defined in view